# How do I upgrade Android native app to new version based on NativeScript while keeping data from old app?

Tags: nativescript

I want to update an existing Android app (not made with NativeScript), with a new one (made with NativeScript).

The old app stored some user data in a SQLite database. I want this to survive the upgrade.

Now, I have the same app-id in the new app, as the old, so that part is in place.  To test if the database survives though, I have started the Android Emulator with the old app, created a few records, then published the native script version using

```
tns run android --bundle --device=1
```

and this correctly replaces the old app with the new code, but at the same time it seems to wipe the database, which is otherwise correctly stored in /data/data/*app-id*/databases

Is this due to the `tns` deployment for debugging possibly starting out wiping the system, or something else ?

How do you guys test this?

Edit: Apparently the uninstalling after each compile, rather than upgrading is a known thing, tracked in their [Github as issue #3382](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3382)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tns run android --bundle` produces a development version of APK which would not match the signature of your production version of APK built with native Android.

If you use the same signing certificate you used for the production native app while running app / building your {N} version of APK, then you will survive the upgrade by default.

So your command may look like

```
tns [build|run] android --bundle --release --keyStorePath /path/to/keystore --keyStorePassword keystore-password --keyStoreAlias keystore-alias --keyStoreAliasPassword keystore-alias-passwrd
```

Read more on [docs.](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps)

**Edit:** CLI seems to have a [known issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3382) with `tns run`, instead of replacing the APK, it deletes the old version and installs new version. So it should not be a problem when you publish the APK built with `tns build`. Credits to @DimitarTachev.

Comment: Thanks. I tried again, with recompiling both my old and new app with the same key, but it still seems the `tns run` whacks the entire /data/data/app-id folder. I even noticed it when I changed something in my nativescript components, that my database (which I had copied into the AVD manually, just to confirm I could read it correctly), was gone after the watched build has completed.

Comment: My bad. After adding --release to my `tns build`, and deploying the apk via `adb` i was able to get it to actually upgrade, keeping my data intact.

I take it, that the normal `tns run` does an `adb uninstall` followed by `adb install` or some such, since it cleans out the /databases/ directory after each compile.

Comment: The problem is caused exactly by the uninstall and install calls. Its a known limitation of the NativeScript CLI. You can comment and vote for its improvement here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3382

Comment: As a workaround during your app development, you can try storing your database in /data/local/tmp